# route laravel not defined

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.8

i have this route:

```
Route::get('blog/search', 'web\BlogController@localSearch')->name($this->prefix.'blogSingle.localSearch');
```

this route it´s inside group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => $locale, 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], function(){
        //Route::get('/', 'Web\HomeController@index')->name($this->prefix.'home.index');
        Route::get('/', 'Web\ManagerController@index')->name($this->prefix.'home.index');
        Route::get('about', 'Web\AboutController@index')->name($this->prefix.'about.index');
        Route::get('contact', 'Web\ContactController@index')->name($this->prefix.'contact.index');
        Route::get('help', 'Web\HelpController@index')->name($this->prefix.'help.index');
        Route::get('local/{url}', 'Web\LocalController@index')->name($this->prefix.'local.index');
        Route::get('privacy-policy', 'Web\PrivacyController@index')->name($this->prefix.'privacy.index');
        Route::get('managers', 'Web\ManagerController@index')->name($this->prefix.'manager.index');
        Route::get('blog', 'Web\BlogController@index')->name($this->prefix.'blog.index');
        Route::get('search', 'Web\SearchController@index')->name($this->prefix.'search.index');
        Route::get('suggest-local', 'Web\SuggestController@index')->name($this->prefix.'suggest.index');
        Route::get('terms-conditions', 'Web\TermController@index')->name($this->prefix.'term.index');
        Route::get('blog/{url}', 'web\BlogController@show')->name($this->prefix.'blogSingle.show');
        Route::get('blog/likeit/{id}', 'web\BlogController@likeit')->name($this->prefix.'blogSingle.likeit');
        Route::get('blog/search', 'web\BlogController@localSearch')->name($this->prefix.'blogSingle.localSearch');

        Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name($this->prefix.'password.reset');
        Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name($this->prefix.'verification.verify');
   });
}
```

but i need call to action form:

```
<form action="{{ route('blog/search') }}" method="get" class="fl-wrap" id="searchRestaurant">
```

and when send my form, returned this:

```
Route [blog/search] not defined. (View: C:\wamp64\www\guiaPaladar\resources\views\layouts\right_sidebar_blog.blade.php)
```

this error appear when blade load, so i can´t do anything

i don´t show my wrong, others routes i can use in other form, for example `blog/likeit/{id}` i used in href to add like in post blog...

i hope that anybody can help me, please. Sorry for my english

Thanks

Comment: You should call the `named route` not the link to the route inside the `route function` : [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-named-routes)

Comment: @Tithira thanks for your response, but if i call to named route return same error

Comment: have you checked your route list using  `php artisan r:l` ? you might be able to find the exact route name, or use the link straightaway and check

Comment: yes i´m show it in route list, but my routes it´s in group and it´s have a prefix that it´s a language with blog/likeit/{id} wasn´t any problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the route `blog/search` is registered after using `php artisan route:list` to check. However, your change is not reflected; You may have to clear cache. Please use the following command:

```
php artisan route:clear
```